# Debian squeeze backports vs PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql, debian

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL 9.1 on a Debian 6.0.5 system, via Synpatic, or apt-get, or dpkg, or anything that will actually work.  I keep running into snags in what seems to be metadata errors in the Backports repository, or bugs in the tools.

After adding

```
# Backports for squeeze
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list and running apt-get update, I was able to see most of the postgresql-9.1 packages in Synaptic, but it wouldn't show the two libpq packages from 9.1.  I downloaded those separately and installed them with dpkg -i, now when I attempt to install any of the 9.1 package via Synaptic or apt-get, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-client-9.1 : Depends: postgresql-client-common (>= 115~) but 113 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So why haven't the -common packages been updated, if the others already depend on the updated version that isn't there?  This is so confusing.

Answer (score 9):

You did not provide the `apt-get` command line, but given the error message, it's quite plausible that the `-t` option is missing.

Try to add this option for apt-get to prioritize the packages from the backports release:

```
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install postgresql-9.1
```

If it doesn't work, please update your question with the result of

```
 COLUMNS=200 dpkg -l 'postgres*' 'libpq*'
```

that will help to know at which point the 9.1 install is stalled and if there are older versions of some packages in the way.